# Unity3D Switching Camera Modes - Orbit to FreeCam Jumping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, transform

I am creating a custom camera to view a 3D object. The camera is normally a fly cam but on drag of an object, I want the camera to orbit the object. I have achieved this already but the camera jumps between positions when swapping between the modes. How would I smooth this so the camera maintains the same position after orbit and the user can continue on the fly cam mode from this position. Here is my code:

```
    if (!rotateToggle)
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)){
            rotationX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * cameraSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
            rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * cameraSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        rotationY = Mathf.Clamp(rotationY, -90, 90);

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationX, Vector3.up);
        transform.localRotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationY, Vector3.left);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightShift))
        {
            cameraSpeed = 150f;
        }
        else
        {
            cameraSpeed = 50f;
        }


        transform.position += transform.forward * cameraSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position += transform.right * cameraSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime;
    }else{

        rotationX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * RotateAmount;
        rotationY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * RotateAmount;

        Vector3 angles = transform.eulerAngles;
        angles.z = 0;
        transform.eulerAngles = angles;
        transform.RotateAround(rotationTarget.position, Vector3.up, rotationX);
        transform.RotateAround(rotationTarget.position, Vector3.left, -rotationY);
        transform.LookAt(rotationTarget);

    }
```

rotateToggle is true when the user is dragging the object and rotationTarget is the orbit target's transform.

Thanks!

Edit: On further investigation, it is purely the rotation angle and not the actual position as stated earlier! Thanks again

Edit2: To further clarify, I am wanting to be able to maintain the values of rotation between:

```
transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationX, Vector3.up);
transform.localRotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationY, Vector3.left);
```

And:

```
            transform.eulerAngles = angles;
            transform.RotateAround(rotationTarget.position, Vector3.up, rotationX);
            transform.RotateAround(rotationTarget.position, Vector3.left, -rotationY);
            transform.LookAt(rotationTarget);
```

when swapping camera modes

Answer (score 1):

This could be achived using Vector3.Lerp and Coroutines.

Whenever your rotateToggle-flag changes its value - probably when a button is pressed or on mouse click - start a coroutine (more info about [coroutines here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)) and interpolate the position and rotation using Vector3.Lerp (or Quaternion.Lerp for Rotations may also work - link to the Vector3.Lerp documentation [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html)). So, you will get a smooth transition between both states and may also adjust, how long the transition will take.

While the camera position and rotation is lerped this way, you should a) lock user unteractions and b) don't execute your code posted in your question, since they would interfere with the coroutine (the code above would set the rotation and position to its "end state" immediately, while the coroutine would set it to a variable "transition state").

Unfortunately, I don't have a sample code at hand right now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but on further investigation, lerping would not be necessary, In my case all I want to do it maintain the viewing angle between the 2 camera modes as the position is already maintained. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by hacking together some lerps and allowing the velocity to continuously increase:

```
        if (!rotateToggle)
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            {
                rotationX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * cameraSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
                rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * cameraSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
            }

            rotationY = Mathf.Clamp(rotationY, -90, 90);

            transform.localRotation = transform.localRotation * Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationX, Vector3.up);
            transform.localRotation = transform.localRotation * Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationY, Vector3.left);
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.x, transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.y, 0);

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightShift))
            {
                cameraSpeed = 150f;
            }
            else
            {
                cameraSpeed = 50f;
            }


            transform.position += transform.forward * cameraSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.position += transform.right * cameraSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime;
            rotationX = Mathf.Lerp(rotationX, 0f, 0.1f);
            rotationY = Mathf.Lerp(rotationY, 0f, 0.1f);

        }
        else
        {

            rotationX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * RotateAmount;
            rotationY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * RotateAmount;

            Vector3 angles = transform.eulerAngles;
            angles.z = 0;
            transform.eulerAngles = angles;
            transform.RotateAround(rotationTarget.position, Vector3.up, rotationX);
            rotationY = Mathf.Clamp(rotationY, -30, 30);

            transform.RotateAround(rotationTarget.position, Vector3.left, -rotationY);
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.x, transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.y, 0);
        }
```

I also added a lookat coroutine to smooth the transition:

```
IEnumerator LerpToTarget()
{
    float time = 0;
    while (time < 0.1f)
    {
        Vector3 pos = rotationTarget.transform.position-transform.position;
        var newRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(pos);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, newRot, 0.1f);
        time += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
    StartCoroutine(LookAtTarget());

}

IEnumerator LookAtTarget()
{
    while (rotateToggle)
    {
        transform.LookAt(rotationTarget);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

This can definitely be improved as there is still a few issues with up and down orbiting.